# SVG - CSS - draw animation on certain svg path

Tags: css, animation, svg, css-animations

I have a kind of like Frankenstein svg with a scar on his face. What I would like to have is that his scar renders delayed. Kind of like drawing animations.
For the sake of completeness, it looks like: [image]

The path of the scar in his face is:

```
<path id="scar" d="..."/>
```

As you can see I gave the path an id. In my CSS class I tried to assign the animation to the id:

```
#scar {
    animation-name: draw;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }

@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

But that did not work out...Someone any ideas?

### Edit

full svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 511.999 511.999" style="enable-background:new 0 0 511.999 511.999;" xml:space="preserve">
<path style="fill:#E6E6E6;" d="M303.852,190.448c6.972,0,12.645-5.672,12.645-12.643c0-0.591-0.041-1.177-0.123-1.758h-25.039
    c-0.082,0.58-0.123,1.167-0.123,1.758C291.21,184.776,296.882,190.448,303.852,190.448z"/>
<path style="fill:#81AF31;" d="M138.086,170.102c-1.694,0.196-2.784,0.609-3.24,1.228c-2.083,2.834,2.176,25.193,2.176,25.193
    c4.459,23.446,11.74,34.058,15.485,34.105c5.253,0.063,7.752-0.294,9.335-1.004c-5.151-15.979-8.764-33.807-10.78-53.428
    C148.651,172.703,143.261,169.499,138.086,170.102z"/>
<path style="fill:#333333;" d="M157.9,147.714c2.222-3.334,4.743-7.113,4.743-9.26V43.563c0-3.238,2.624-5.863,5.863-5.863H343.49
    c3.239,0,5.863,2.625,5.863,5.863v94.891c0,2.148,2.52,5.926,4.743,9.26c2.709,4.06,5.662,8.504,6.969,13.459
    c1.834-0.922,3.77-1.629,5.747-2.117V34.668c0-11.647-9.476-21.122-21.123-21.122H166.305c-11.647,0-21.122,9.476-21.122,21.122
    v124.386c1.978,0.487,3.915,1.193,5.748,2.114C152.24,156.214,155.194,151.772,157.9,147.714z"/>
<g>
    <path style="fill:#81AF31;" d="M255.999,225.206c3.826,0,6.939-3.114,6.939-6.942v-42.218h-13.881v42.218
        C249.057,222.091,252.171,225.206,255.999,225.206z"/>
    <path style="fill:#81AF31;" d="M360.935,176.195c-2.017,19.622-5.628,37.451-10.78,53.43c1.582,0.711,4.081,1.068,9.333,1.003
        c3.748-0.047,11.028-10.659,15.486-34.105c0,0,4.26-22.359,2.177-25.193c-0.456-0.619-1.545-1.033-3.241-1.228
        C368.741,169.502,363.349,172.702,360.935,176.195z"/>
    <path style="fill:#81AF31;" d="M298.518,256.794l-4.072,49.296c6.228-6.313,10.445-14.199,14.77-22.28
        c2.907-5.436,5.915-11.056,9.545-16.162c9.219-12.964,16.482-28.583,21.787-46.663
        C323.995,242.358,305.862,253.062,298.518,256.794z"/>
</g>
<path style="fill:#808080;" d="M321.407,308.647h21.395c1.826,0,2.751-1.536,2.751-4.564c0-3.029-0.925-4.564-2.751-4.564h-21.395
    V308.647z"/>
<path style="fill:#E6E6E6;" d="M208.143,190.448c6.972,0,12.644-5.672,12.644-12.643c0-0.591-0.041-1.177-0.123-1.758h-25.039
    c-0.082,0.58-0.123,1.167-0.123,1.758C195.5,184.776,201.172,190.448,208.143,190.448z"/>
<g>
    <path style="fill:#81AF31;" d="M202.315,306.081v25.404c0.072,0.749,0.308,3.203,0.715,7.031
        c4.108,19.926,26.153,35.31,52.967,36.028c26.787-0.716,48.813-16.068,52.954-35.962c0.414-3.854,0.655-6.327,0.728-7.092v-25.408
        c-9.731,13.82-24.207,25.365-53.68,25.367h-0.001h-0.001h-0.001c0,0,0,0-0.001,0C226.523,331.448,212.047,319.903,202.315,306.081z
        "/>
    <path style="fill:#81AF31;" d="M281.955,314.86l2.903-35.145h-57.722l2.901,35.144c6.667,3.057,15.036,4.865,25.961,4.865
        C266.92,319.723,275.289,317.916,281.955,314.86z"/>
</g>
<g>
    <path style="fill:#333333;" d="M348.926,426.596c-0.827-1.343-1.078-2.962-0.697-4.492s1.363-2.841,2.723-3.64l35.987-21.1
        c-20.172-18.65-51.77-43.244-66.646-54.629c-2.971,26.921-12.152,100.466-28.929,155.716h47.091l29.045-41.689L348.926,426.596z"/>
    <path style="fill:#333333;" d="M125.056,397.365l35.987,21.1c1.36,0.797,2.342,2.109,2.723,3.64c0.381,1.53,0.13,3.15-0.697,4.492
        l-18.575,30.167l29.045,41.689h47.064c-16.775-54.741-25.946-128.682-28.91-155.711
        C176.815,354.128,145.225,378.718,125.056,397.365z"/>
</g>
<path style="fill:#808080;" d="M259.344,386.123c-0.449,0.11-6.243,0.11-6.691,0c-18.519-1.174-34.954-8.436-46.249-19.307
    c4.611,35.257,13.223,89.888,26.485,131.636h46.206c13.239-42.128,21.846-96.495,26.465-131.605
    C294.265,377.701,277.844,384.952,259.344,386.123z"/>
<path style="fill:#333333;" d="M338.196,341.72c18.52,14.397,46.087,36.457,62.535,52.573c1.304,1.278,1.938,3.092,1.717,4.904
    c-0.223,1.813-1.278,3.418-2.854,4.342l-37.542,22.011l17.448,28.338c1.223,1.988,1.151,4.511-0.182,6.426l-26.571,38.138h71.719
    v-41.491c0-3.237,2.624-5.863,5.863-5.863s5.863,2.625,5.863,5.863v41.491h61.725c0,0-31.312-91.272-31.438-91.438
    C466.035,406.427,453.946,364.643,338.196,341.72z"/>
<path style="fill:#808080;" d="M190.589,299.519h-21.393c-1.827,0-2.752,1.535-2.752,4.564c0,3.028,0.925,4.564,2.752,4.564h21.393
    V299.519z"/>
<g>
    <path style="fill:#81AF31;" d="M202.782,283.809c4.323,8.08,8.541,15.964,14.766,22.277l-4.07-49.293
        c-7.342-3.731-25.467-14.412-42.016-35.77c5.304,18.064,12.562,33.669,21.774,46.623
        C196.866,272.752,199.873,278.373,202.782,283.809z"/>
    <path style="fill:#81AF31;" d="M221.311,247.539c2.011,0.849,3.396,2.749,3.575,4.924l1.282,15.527h59.659l1.283-15.527
        c0.181-2.183,1.564-4.085,3.587-4.928c0.36-0.151,37.185-16.15,57.28-61.928c0.84-6.081,1.533-12.337,2.036-18.815
        c0.284-3.641-2.744-8.18-5.671-12.569c-3.301-4.949-6.714-10.068-6.714-15.767V49.426h-14.572v13.41
        c0,3.238-2.624,5.863-5.863,5.863s-5.863-2.625-5.863-5.863v-13.41h-18.873v13.41c0,3.238-2.624,5.863-5.863,5.863
        s-5.863-2.625-5.863-5.863v-13.41h-18.872v13.41c0,3.238-2.624,5.863-5.863,5.863c-3.239,0-5.863-2.625-5.863-5.863v-13.41h-18.872
        v13.41c0,3.238-2.624,5.863-5.863,5.863s-5.863-2.625-5.863-5.863v-13.41h-18.872v13.41c0,3.238-2.624,5.863-5.863,5.863
        s-5.863-2.625-5.863-5.863v-13.41h-14.571v89.028c0,5.699-3.412,10.816-6.714,15.765c-2.927,4.389-5.953,8.928-5.669,12.57
        c0.504,6.48,1.197,12.738,2.037,18.819C184.119,231.383,220.941,247.382,221.311,247.539z M198.847,106.109
        c-3.239,0-5.863-2.625-5.863-5.863s2.624-5.863,5.863-5.863h3.435V74.716c0-3.238,2.624-5.863,5.863-5.863
        c3.239,0,5.863,2.625,5.863,5.863v19.668h3.435c3.239,0,5.863,2.625,5.863,5.863c0,3.238-2.624,5.863-5.863,5.863h-3.435v17.998
        h3.435c3.239,0,5.863,2.625,5.863,5.863c0,3.238-2.624,5.863-5.863,5.863h-3.435v12.698c0,3.238-2.624,5.863-5.863,5.863
        c-3.239,0-5.863-2.625-5.863-5.863v-12.698h-3.435c-3.239,0-5.863-2.625-5.863-5.863s2.624-5.863,5.863-5.863h3.435v-17.998
        H198.847z M177.051,176.046c-3.239,0-5.863-2.625-5.863-5.863s2.624-5.863,5.863-5.863h157.895c3.239,0,5.863,2.625,5.863,5.863
        s-2.624,5.863-5.863,5.863h-6.794c0.042,0.583,0.072,1.168,0.072,1.758c0,13.438-10.933,24.369-24.371,24.369
        c-13.437,0-24.368-10.932-24.368-24.369c0-0.59,0.028-1.174,0.072-1.758h-4.891v32.096c9.068,2.563,15.744,10.878,15.744,20.757
        c0,3.238-2.624,5.863-5.863,5.863s-5.863-2.625-5.863-5.863c0-3.34-1.672-6.287-4.215-8.076
        c-1.254,9.083-9.047,16.107-18.468,16.107c-9.425,0-17.221-7.027-18.472-16.114c-2.545,1.789-4.214,4.742-4.214,8.083
        c0,3.238-2.624,5.863-5.863,5.863c-3.239,0-5.863-2.625-5.863-5.863c0-9.88,6.673-18.214,15.744-20.777v-32.076h-4.89
        c0.042,0.583,0.072,1.168,0.072,1.758c0,13.438-10.932,24.369-24.37,24.369c-13.437,0-24.369-10.932-24.369-24.369
        c0-0.59,0.028-1.174,0.072-1.758H177.051z"/>
</g>
<path style="fill:#333333;" d="M132.496,453.888l17.448-28.338l-37.543-22.011c-1.576-0.924-2.63-2.529-2.854-4.342
    c-0.222-1.813,0.413-3.626,1.717-4.904c16.444-16.111,44.004-38.165,62.524-52.562c-58.347,11.568-89.687,28.218-106.499,40.205
    c-16.79,11.97-21.748,24.973-21.771,25.079c-0.047,0.203-31.437,91.438-31.437,91.438h61.725v-41.491
    c0-3.237,2.624-5.863,5.863-5.863c3.239,0,5.863,2.625,5.863,5.863v41.491h71.719l-26.572-38.138
    C131.344,458.398,131.273,455.875,132.496,453.888z"/>
<path id="scar" style="fill:#333333;" d="M198.847,124.107c-3.239,0-5.863,2.625-5.863,5.863c0,3.238,2.624,5.863,5.863,5.863h3.435v12.698
    c0,3.238,2.624,5.863,5.863,5.863c3.239,0,5.863-2.625,5.863-5.863v-12.698h3.435c3.239,0,5.863-2.625,5.863-5.863
    s-2.624-5.863-5.863-5.863h-3.435v-17.998h3.435c3.239,0,5.863-2.625,5.863-5.863s-2.624-5.863-5.863-5.863h-3.435V74.716
    c0-3.238-2.624-5.863-5.863-5.863c-3.239,0-5.863,2.625-5.863,5.863v19.668h-3.435c-3.239,0-5.863,2.625-5.863,5.863
    c0,3.238,2.624,5.863,5.863,5.863h3.435v17.998H198.847z"/>
<path d="M208.143,202.174c13.438,0,24.37-10.932,24.37-24.369c0-0.59-0.028-1.174-0.072-1.758h4.89v32.076
    c-9.07,2.564-15.744,10.897-15.744,20.777c0,3.238,2.624,5.863,5.863,5.863s5.863-2.625,5.863-5.863c0-3.34,1.67-6.293,4.214-8.083
    c1.251,9.086,9.047,16.114,18.472,16.114c9.422,0,17.215-7.024,18.468-16.107c2.543,1.788,4.215,4.736,4.215,8.076
    c0,3.238,2.624,5.863,5.863,5.863s5.863-2.625,5.863-5.863c0-9.878-6.676-18.194-15.744-20.757v-32.096h4.891
    c-0.042,0.583-0.072,1.168-0.072,1.758c0,13.438,10.931,24.369,24.368,24.369c13.438,0,24.371-10.932,24.371-24.369
    c0-0.59-0.028-1.174-0.072-1.758h6.794c3.239,0,5.863-2.625,5.863-5.863s-2.624-5.863-5.863-5.863H177.051
    c-3.239,0-5.863,2.625-5.863,5.863s2.624,5.863,5.863,5.863h6.794c-0.042,0.583-0.072,1.168-0.072,1.758
    C183.774,191.242,194.706,202.174,208.143,202.174z M291.333,176.046h25.039c0.082,0.58,0.123,1.167,0.123,1.758
    c0,6.971-5.673,12.643-12.645,12.643c-6.97,0-12.642-5.672-12.642-12.643C291.21,177.213,291.251,176.626,291.333,176.046z
     M249.057,176.046h13.881v42.218c0,3.827-3.113,6.942-6.939,6.942c-3.828,0-6.942-3.114-6.942-6.942V176.046z M195.623,176.046
    h25.039c0.082,0.58,0.123,1.167,0.123,1.758c0,6.971-5.672,12.643-12.644,12.643c-6.971,0-12.643-5.672-12.643-12.643
    C195.5,177.213,195.541,176.626,195.623,176.046z"/>
<path d="M477.808,403.997c-1.481-5.345-18.783-54.621-156.401-77.228v-6.396h21.395c8.522,0,14.477-6.698,14.477-16.29
    c0-9.592-5.953-16.29-14.477-16.29h-21.395V285.9c2.209-4.074,4.409-7.938,6.911-11.457c7.047-9.91,13.03-21.192,17.941-33.786
    c3.325,1.314,12.893,1.704,13.377,1.697c16.189-0.202,23.775-27.428,26.858-43.639c0,0,5.216-27.376,0.107-34.327
    c-1.898-2.582-4.607-4.35-8.062-5.298V34.668c0-18.112-14.735-32.848-32.849-32.848H166.305c-18.112,0-32.848,14.736-32.848,32.848
    v124.42c-3.453,0.949-6.163,2.716-8.06,5.298c-5.11,6.952,0.106,34.328,0.106,34.328c3.084,16.211,10.673,43.437,26.857,43.639
    c0.485,0.006,10.055-0.381,13.38-1.694c4.91,12.592,10.892,23.874,17.938,33.783c2.502,3.519,4.703,7.383,6.911,11.456v1.895
    h-21.393c-8.525,0-14.478,6.698-14.478,16.29c0,9.592,5.953,16.29,14.478,16.29h21.393v6.396
    c-137.624,22.609-154.921,71.89-156.401,77.229L0.319,502.408c-0.617,1.792-0.329,3.771,0.77,5.313s2.878,2.458,4.772,2.458h500.274
    c1.895,0,3.673-0.916,4.772-2.458c1.1-1.542,1.388-3.521,0.77-5.313L477.808,403.997z M342.802,299.519
    c1.826,0,2.751,1.535,2.751,4.564c0,3.028-0.925,4.564-2.751,4.564h-21.395v-9.127H342.802z M318.76,267.646
    c-3.63,5.105-6.637,10.726-9.545,16.162c-4.324,8.081-8.542,15.967-14.77,22.28l4.072-49.296
    c7.344-3.732,25.476-14.436,42.029-35.811C335.241,239.064,327.979,254.682,318.76,267.646z M255.995,331.449
    c0.001,0,0.001,0,0.001,0h0.001h0.001H256c29.473-0.001,43.949-11.546,53.68-25.367v25.408c-0.074,0.765-0.315,3.238-0.728,7.092
    c-4.142,19.893-26.167,35.246-52.954,35.962c-26.814-0.716-48.859-16.102-52.967-36.028c-0.408-3.827-0.645-6.282-0.715-7.031
    v-25.404C212.047,319.903,226.523,331.448,255.995,331.449z M227.137,279.714h57.722l-2.903,35.145
    c-6.667,3.056-15.035,4.863-25.958,4.863c-10.924,0-19.293-1.808-25.961-4.865L227.137,279.714z M373.911,170.102
    c1.694,0.196,2.785,0.609,3.241,1.228c2.081,2.834-2.177,25.193-2.177,25.193c-4.458,23.446-11.739,34.058-15.486,34.105
    c-5.252,0.066-7.751-0.292-9.333-1.003c5.152-15.979,8.764-33.809,10.78-53.43C363.349,172.702,368.741,169.502,373.911,170.102z
     M145.183,34.668c0-11.647,9.475-21.122,21.122-21.122H345.69c11.647,0,21.123,9.476,21.123,21.122v124.389
    c-1.978,0.487-3.914,1.194-5.747,2.117c-1.306-4.955-4.261-9.398-6.969-13.459c-2.222-3.334-4.743-7.113-4.743-9.26V43.563
    c0-3.238-2.624-5.863-5.863-5.863H168.506c-3.239,0-5.863,2.625-5.863,5.863v94.891c0,2.147-2.52,5.926-4.743,9.26
    c-2.708,4.058-5.66,8.5-6.968,13.453c-1.834-0.922-3.771-1.628-5.748-2.114V34.668H145.183z M152.508,230.629
    c-3.745-0.047-11.026-10.659-15.485-34.105c0,0-4.26-22.359-2.176-25.193c0.456-0.619,1.544-1.033,3.24-1.228
    c5.176-0.604,10.565,2.601,12.977,6.094c2.017,19.621,5.63,37.449,10.78,53.428C160.26,230.334,157.76,230.692,152.508,230.629z
     M164.023,185.608c-0.841-6.081-1.534-12.339-2.037-18.819c-0.284-3.641,2.743-8.181,5.669-12.57
    c3.301-4.949,6.714-10.067,6.714-15.765V49.426h14.571v13.41c0,3.238,2.624,5.863,5.863,5.863s5.863-2.625,5.863-5.863v-13.41
    h18.872v13.41c0,3.238,2.624,5.863,5.863,5.863c3.239,0,5.863-2.625,5.863-5.863v-13.41h18.872v13.41
    c0,3.238,2.624,5.863,5.863,5.863s5.863-2.625,5.863-5.863v-13.41h18.872v13.41c0,3.238,2.624,5.863,5.863,5.863
    s5.863-2.625,5.863-5.863v-13.41h18.873v13.41c0,3.238,2.624,5.863,5.863,5.863s5.863-2.625,5.863-5.863v-13.41h14.572v89.028
    c0,5.699,3.413,10.817,6.714,15.767c2.927,4.389,5.954,8.927,5.671,12.569c-0.504,6.479-1.196,12.735-2.036,18.815
    c-20.095,45.778-56.92,61.777-57.28,61.928c-2.023,0.843-3.405,2.745-3.587,4.928l-1.283,15.527h-59.661l-1.282-15.527
    c-0.179-2.175-1.564-4.076-3.575-4.924C220.941,247.382,184.119,231.383,164.023,185.608z M171.462,221.023
    c16.549,21.358,34.675,32.039,42.016,35.77l4.07,49.293c-6.225-6.313-10.443-14.197-14.766-22.277
    c-2.908-5.436-5.916-11.058-9.546-16.163C184.024,254.691,176.766,239.088,171.462,221.023z M169.197,308.647
    c-1.827,0-2.752-1.536-2.752-4.564c0-3.029,0.925-4.564,2.752-4.564h21.393v9.127H169.197z M87.531,498.453v-41.491
    c0-3.238-2.624-5.863-5.863-5.863c-3.239,0-5.863,2.625-5.863,5.863v41.491H14.08c0,0,31.39-91.236,31.437-91.438
    c0.025-0.107,4.981-13.11,21.771-25.079c16.813-11.986,48.152-28.637,106.499-40.204c-18.52,14.397-46.079,36.451-62.524,52.562
    c-1.304,1.278-1.938,3.091-1.717,4.904c0.223,1.813,1.278,3.418,2.854,4.342l37.543,22.011l-17.448,28.338
    c-1.223,1.988-1.151,4.511,0.182,6.426l26.572,38.138H87.531V498.453z M173.541,498.453l-29.045-41.689l18.575-30.167
    c0.827-1.343,1.078-2.962,0.697-4.492c-0.381-1.53-1.363-2.842-2.723-3.64l-35.987-21.1c20.169-18.647,51.759-43.236,66.638-54.623
    c2.964,27.029,12.136,100.969,28.91,155.711h-47.065V498.453z M232.888,498.453c-13.261-41.748-21.875-96.377-26.485-131.636
    c11.297,10.871,27.731,18.133,46.249,19.307c0.448,0.11,6.242,0.11,6.691,0c18.5-1.173,34.921-8.423,46.216-19.277
    c-4.619,35.112-13.227,89.479-26.465,131.605h-46.206V498.453z M291.366,498.453c16.777-55.25,25.958-128.796,28.929-155.716
    c14.875,11.385,46.474,35.979,66.646,54.629l-35.987,21.1c-1.36,0.799-2.342,2.109-2.723,3.64c-0.381,1.53-0.13,3.15,0.697,4.492
    l18.575,30.167l-29.045,41.689H291.366z M436.193,498.453v-41.491c0-3.238-2.624-5.863-5.863-5.863s-5.863,2.625-5.863,5.863v41.491
    h-71.719l26.571-38.138c1.334-1.915,1.405-4.438,0.182-6.426l-17.448-28.338l37.542-22.011c1.576-0.924,2.63-2.529,2.854-4.342
    c0.222-1.812-0.413-3.626-1.717-4.904c-16.448-16.115-44.015-38.176-62.535-52.573c115.75,22.922,127.839,64.707,128.283,65.294
    c0.125,0.167,31.438,91.438,31.438,91.438h-61.725V498.453z"/>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
```

components hml:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1 class="text-focus-in">Welcome, to shock-me.de</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="mt-6 row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="slide-in-fwd-center" src="./../../../assets/ghost.svg" alt="ghost" width="150px" height="auto">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 511.999 511.999" style="enable-background:new 0 0 511.999 511.999;" xml:space="preserve">
...   <== the paths included above
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you need this ?

remember that you need to have an stroke on path to animate it.

```css
svg { width: 200px; }
#scar {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  fill: none;
  stroke-dasharray: 900; 
  stroke-dashoffset: 900;
  animation: draw 2s linear 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: #000;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 511.999 511.999" style="enable-background:new 0 0 511.999 511.999;" xml:space="preserve">

<path id="scar" d="M198.847,124.107c-3.239,0-5.863,2.625-5.863,5.863c0,3.238,2.624,5.863,5.863,5.863h3.435v12.698
    c0,3.238,2.624,5.863,5.863,5.863c3.239,0,5.863-2.625,5.863-5.863v-12.698h3.435c3.239,0,5.863-2.625,5.863-5.863
    s-2.624-5.863-5.863-5.863h-3.435v-17.998h3.435c3.239,0,5.863-2.625,5.863-5.863s-2.624-5.863-5.863-5.863h-3.435V74.716
    c0-3.238-2.624-5.863-5.863-5.863c-3.239,0-5.863,2.625-5.863,5.863v19.668h-3.435c-3.239,0-5.863,2.625-5.863,5.863
    c0,3.238,2.624,5.863,5.863,5.863h3.435v17.998H198.847z"/>
          </svg>
```